# Is there a way to fix no overload for button_name_clicked matches delegate Eventhandler

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I'm making a program for fun but I get an error using `webbrowser1` and making it visible and invisible using `lcontrolkey` as well I want it to be visible when I click the button

I've asked looked around on google for a couple of days now and no one knows what wrong with it as well I've loaded it in a different for and still the same error

```
    private void btn_YT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, Keys keyData)
    {

            webBrowser1.Navigate(@"https://www.youtube.com/?gl=GB");
            webBrowser1.Visible = true;

            if (keyData == (Keys.LControlKey))
            {
                webBrowser1.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fix this issue");
            }
        }// Add This
```

I wanted the button to make visible the `webbrowser1` and go to the correct URL I put in and then have a keydata using the control key to make it invisible/close it but it's not working. It's coming with no overload for button matches delegate `EventHandler`.

Comment: What is `webBrowser1`? Is it an instance of the WebBrowser class?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the default button-click event handler (you can't add parameters to it). But you can request the key state without any event parameter:

```
private void btn_YT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(@"https://www.youtube.com/?gl=GB");
    webBrowser1.Visible = true;
    if (ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Control))
    {
        webBrowser1.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fix this issue");
    }
}// Add This
```

Comment: still gives me the same problem and when i go to "go to code" it goes to this bit `form1.btn_YT.Click += new System.EventHandler(form1.btn_YT_Click);`

Comment: You get an error during compile? Can you add the method, where you the adding of the event-handler is placed?

Comment: sorry im new to c#  but it wont show the form page and when i click ignore it has nothing but if i remove the thing in the first comment it works but doesn't show me the webbrowser1 thing.

Comment: You use a WinForm project type?

Comment: Please add the method, where you add the event-handler.